# javascript null returns object when used with typeof operator

Tags: javascript

Why does `typeof` return `object` when used with `null`? From my understanding this is a top level property of the global object. References to official documentation would greatly help.

Comment: because in javascript , everything is an object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @Holybreath: While I generally support this statement, primitive values are not objects and `typeof` doesn't actually return the data type of a value (not for all types at least).

Comment: @Felix Kling I was joking)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were
>   represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0.
>   null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 in most platforms).
>   Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the bogus typeof return
>   value. (reference)
>
> A fix was proposed for ECMAScript (via an opt-in), but was rejected.
>   It would have resulted in typeof null === 'null'.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Answer (score 2):

Because the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) says so:

```
Table 20 — typeof Operator Results

 Type of val     Result
---------------------------
  Undefined    "undefined"
  Null         "object"
  Boolean      "boolean"
  Number       "number"
  String       "string"
  ...
```

[And it is also saying:](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11)

> **4.3.11 null value**
>
> primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value

Nevertheless, `null` is still of *data type* Null and you can use `null` where you can use other objects (e.g. accessing a property on `null` throws an error instead of returning `undefined` (for better or worse)).

> From my understanding this is a top level property of the global object.

No, `null` is *literal*, just like `5` is a number literal. `undefined` on the other hand is a global variable (as if it wasn't already confusing enough).

Answer (score 1):

It is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design). In Javascript `null` is an `object`

[Kiro Risk says](http://kiro.me/blog/typeof_null.html)

> The reasoning behind this is that null, in contrast with undefined,
>   was (and still is) often used where objects appear. In other words,
>   null is often used to signify an empty reference to an object. When
>   Brendan Eich created JavaScript, he followed the same paradigm, and it
>   made sense (arguably) to return "object". In fact, the ECMAScript
>   specification defines null as the primitive value that represents the
>   intentional absence of any object value (ECMA-262, 11.4.11).